# How to connect to an Oracle database (in Azure Data Factory) using proxy user authentication / connect through?

Tags: oracle, azure, proxy

I'm looking for some help in figuring out the correct syntax to connect to Oracle from ADF using a proxy user authentication.

The setup is:

- An integration runtime has been setup to connect to an on-premise Oracle instance
- The connection type is on Oracle Service Name
- User name and Password are provided.

When simply using the user name / password combination the connection can be established, and the tables in the (proxy) user schema can be viewed.

However, these are not the correct tables as the setup in the Oracle instance is using connect through / proxy user authentication. Usually, the syntax for login is **username[schema-you-want-to-work-with]** for this but this does not work in Azure Data Factory for me.

I have tried various syntax attempts in the connection JSON, using additional connection properties but not luck. The error message, when logging in with the proxy user authentication, is always

```
ERROR [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied ERROR [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied Activity ID: da224af9-16ad-4674-a4c9-4811be8f726c.
```

Logging in with SQL Plus or SQL Developer works with the same connection string.

Does anyone have an idea how I can log in with the proxy user and see the normal schema content? I'm thinking it may just be a syntax issue but I'm out of ideas.

[Basic successful connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4l0L.png)

[Unsuccessful connection with connect through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axH9Y.png)